# Prime Generator Overflow? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading, generator

I am writing a generator for prime numbers using the sieve of eratosthenes.  I have gotten it to work at generating primes below 521102 but any higher numbers cause the program to crash.  Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int long MAX_NUM = 1000000;
    int long MAX_NUM_ARRAY = MAX_NUM+1;
    int Num_Array [MAX_NUM_ARRAY];
    std::fill_n(Num_Array, MAX_NUM_ARRAY, 3);
    int long sieve_prime = 2;
    int long sieve_prime_constant = 0;
    Num_Array [0] = 1;
    Num_Array [1] = 1;



    while (sieve_prime_constant <= MAX_NUM_ARRAY)
    {
        if (Num_Array [sieve_prime_constant] == 1)  
        {

            sieve_prime_constant++;
        }

        else
        {
        Num_Array [sieve_prime_constant] = 0;  
        sieve_prime=sieve_prime_constant; 
            while (sieve_prime<=MAX_NUM_ARRAY - sieve_prime_constant)  
            {
                sieve_prime = sieve_prime + sieve_prime_constant;
                Num_Array [sieve_prime] = 1;
            }

            if (sieve_prime_constant <= MAX_NUM_ARRAY)
            {
                sieve_prime_constant++;
                sieve_prime = sieve_prime_constant;
            }
        }
    } 
return 0;
}
```

I put MAX_NUM in as 1000000 and it doesn't work.  But as I said before, numbers below 521102 do work.  I need to be able to test higher numbers.  What is my problem, and how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Thanks for the responses.  I tried the solution of dynamically allocating the array.  It worked well, to an extent.  After setting MAX_NUM to around 500million I get this error when i run the program...

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
    what():  std::bad_alloc

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Having a 500million roof is close to acceptable, but higher would still be better?
Any other ideas?

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: You're probably running on Windows and are probably exceeding the maximum limit on the stack.  Either dynamically allocate the array or allocate it statically (possibly outside the function) or find a way to increase the stack size.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the idiom for using long ints is to declare them simply as `long`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're on Windows, your stack is too small(1MB by default) to fit the following variable in the stack frame:

`int Num_Array [MAX_NUM_ARRAY];`

You should allocate it in the heap:

```
int *Num_Array = new int[MAX_NUM_ARRAY];
...
delete[] Num_Array;
```

Comment: "You should allocate it in the heap." - Why? Isn't (un)initialized memory (DATA or BSS) good enough?

Comment: @H2CO3 Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that would just unnecessarily increase the size of the executable?

Comment: If you have appetit for a bit of premature-optimization-war: why not? Well, it may increase the executable size, but it will also be faster because it has a constant address.

Comment: @H2CO3 Oh, then I guess we could both agree that we can allocate it in the heap during the initialization.

Comment: @JoesphH Just to make it clear: it's **discouraged** to heap-allocate static data which is alive during the whole lifetime of the program.

Comment: @H2CO3 This is getting ridiculous. What difference does it make in the code provided by the OP?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because you're smashing the stack. How about moving the array out of the `main()` function?

```
#define MAX_NUM = 1000000;
#define MAX_NUM_ARRAY (MAX_NUM + 1)
int Num_Array[MAX_NUM_ARRAY];

int main()
{
    // etc.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're using `std::fill_n` indicates you're actually writing C++, not C.

You can drastically reduce the memory consumption of your program by using a real bool array instead of an int array. Since you're using C++, you can get a Boolean array using `std::vector<bool>`. Unlike `bool[n]`, `std::vector<bool>(n)` only takes up n bits (`bool[n]` takes up maybe 8n bits, or whatever the smallest alignment is on your machine/compiler, and your `Num_Array[n]` actually takes up 32n bits since you're using 32-bit integers to store Boolean values).

The other comments suggest you store this value on the heap instead of on the stack. `std::vector<bool>` will do that for you automatically.

Comment: The way my program is written it uses three variables in the array.  One is arbitrary, so I can see the logic behind the Boolean array.  But how would I implement this so that that other arbitrary variable can still be included? - Thanks

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like the only values you check for or set are 0 or 1. Since after checking for 1, your code sets it to 0 anyway (without checking for 3), I think it would have the same effect if you initialize the entire array to 0 instead of 3. Then you can store everything as a single bit.